# Access 3rd parties codes when using namespace PhP 5.5

Tags: php, namespaces

I am developing with php 5.5, I provided code of my file here

```
   <?php
     require_once  'jsonrpcphp/includes/jsonRPCClient.php';
     class Client
     {
         private $remoteMain;
         public function __construct($param)
         {
            $this->remoteMain = new jsonRPCClient('http://
                urlTofile/nameOfFile.php');
```

This codes works absolutely fine but the issue comes when I need to put a namespace for the file as soon as I put a namespace at the top of the file, for example:

```
 <?php
    namespace packagename\subPackage;

     require_once  'jsonrpcphp/includes/jsonRPCClient.php';

     class Client
```

This error will be displayed

```
        Class 'packagename\subPackage\jsonRPCClient' not found in
```

The question is this:
how to access a class which is not in my namespace and provided from 3rd parties when I need to have namespaces

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in `namespace packagename\subPackage`, then `new jsonRPCClient` refers to the class `packagename\subPackage\jsonRPCClient`. If you want to use a class from the global namespace, you need to explicitly specify that:

```
new \jsonRPCClient
```

Alternatively, explicitly alias the class at the top of the file:

```
use jsonRPCClient;

new jsonRPCClient(...)
```

Please RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php